# How to grow number smoothly from 0 to 5,000,000

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, math

This is probably basic math that I don't seem to remember.

I'm trying to get from 0 to 5,000,000 in 10 seconds while having all the numbers ticking. I don't have to have the number reach exactly 5,000,000 because I can just do a conditional for it to stop when it's over.

Right now I have this:

```
count+= 123456

if (count > 5000000) {
    count = 5000000;
}
```

It gives the sense of number moving you know? But It really starts off too high. I wanted to gradually climb up.

Comment: perInterval=total/(period*frameRate)

Comment: What do you mean by "having all the numbers ticking"? You can't display every single integer between 0 and 5,000,000 in only 10 seconds, but do you just want it to look to the user as if all digits are changing? If so, just add an odd number like 24987 (or whatever) each time you update the display: http://jsfiddle.net/EGVnC/

Comment: >but do you just want it to look to the user as if all digits are changing?

exactly.

Comment: Is this supposed in Javascript or AS3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tween:

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.Regular;

var count = 0;
var tween:Tween = new Tween(this, "count", Regular.easeInOut,0,5000000,10, true);
```

This will tween you variable count from 0 to 5000000 in 10 seconds. Read about these classes if you want to expand on this code.

- [Tween](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html)
- [TweenEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/TweenEvent.html)

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
function timedCounter(finalValue, seconds, callback){

  var startTime = (new Date).getTime();
  var milliseconds = seconds*1000;

  (function update(){

    var currentTime = (new Date).getTime();
    var value = finalValue*(currentTime - startTime)/milliseconds;

    if(value >= finalValue)
      value = finalValue;
    else
      setTimeout(update, 0);

    callback && callback(value);

  })();

}

timedCounter(5000000, 10, function(value){
  // Do something with value
});
```

### Demo

Note that with a number as big as `5000000` you won't see the last couple digits change. You would only see that with a small number like `5000`. You could fix that; perhaps by adding in some randomness:

```
value += Math.floor(Math.random()*(finalValue/10000 + 1));
```

### Demo with randomness

Comment: I wish I was smart enough to figure this out... thank you so much

Comment: I did have one other question. How would you start off slow from 0 and then as it got closer to the final number it would get faster?

Comment: You can always use TweenLite to have the same effect with all the easing effects you want ;) Google for TweenLite

Comment: @Paulpro Can you please explain me what does the line callback && callback(value) means? I mean, why use "&&" ? Won't the callback(value) be enough?

Comment: @CreativeMagic It's basically shorthand for `if(callback){ callback(value); }`. It just prevents an error if no argument is passed in for the callback. There will still be an error if something other than a function is passed in though, like `timedCounter(500000, 10, 1);`

Comment: @Tom You would have to change the line: `var value = finalValue*(currentTime - startTime)/milliseconds;`. That is a linear function that grows from `0` to `finalValue` over a domain from `0` to `milliseconds`. You could define a quadratic or sine function that grows at a faster rate.